# If I add a new feature xgboost parameters will have to change?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

If I got the best accuracy for some table information from this below feature
if I add a new feature which parameters should I change to get the new result?
or at least which feature?

```
xgb = XGBClassifier(
     bagging_fraction= 0.8,
     boosting= 'gbdt',
    colsample_bytree= 0.7,
    feature_fraction= 0.9,
    learning_rate= 0.05,
    max_bin= 32,
    max_depth= 10,
    min_child_weight= 11,
    missing= -999,
    n_estimators= 400,
    nthread= 4,
    num_leaves= 80,
    objective= 'multiclass',
    predictor= 'gpu_predictor',
    seed= 1337,
    silent= 1,
    subsample= 0.8,
    tree_method= 'gpu_hist',
    verbose= True
)
```

Comment: Hi. There is no general rule. The rule of thumb is that you should try to adjust all parameters. Note, however, that the new optimum could be virtually identical to the original one and in some parameters more close than in others. It all depends on the data